# index Routing CodeIgniter with many Parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing, config

i have a link that is
Example.com/Entertainment/Cinema/200

i want to get the values from the link base on Codeignitor Controller

My default Controller is News

```
class News extends CI_Controller {
public function index($p1="",$p2="",$p3="")
{
    echo $p1,$p2,$p3;
}
function _remap($p1,$p2,$p3){

    $this->_index($p1,$p2,$p3);
}
```

i want to access it like this
www.Example.com/Entertainment/Cinema/774/

but i only can only echo the $p1 how todo this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **URI Routing**

try using this:

```
$route['news/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'news/index';
```

now you can have a URL like this:

```
example.com/news/Entertainment/Cinema/774
```

For additional info. got to this page:

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

But you can also access your param without using URI routing just set you URL like this:

```
 example.com/news/index/Entertainment/Cinema/774
```

you just need to add `index` between your controller name(class) and your parameters, for CI to know that you are trying to access the index method in your controller(news).

Comment: thanks, vien mar, but i dont want to use example.com/news/Entertainment/Cinema/774 i want to use the link without news, example.com/Entertainment/Cinema/774
i use ci basic routing like $route['(:any)']='news/index/$1/$2/$3' ot works but the 404 page cant come out. any ideas ?

Comment: try $route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']='news/index/$1/$2/$3'

Comment: ok vien mar i think it would work, i will try that ASAP thankyou